# Kotlin Gracefully close android application

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to close app with:

```
finishAffinity()
System.exit(0)
this@MainActivity.finish()
exitProcess(0)
```

With finishAffinity app closes with animation but when I run app againg I can see the old data. With System.exit or exitProcess the app terminates suddently, without than nice fadeout animation but all data is erased and not available after app restart.
How to combine the two - so to erase all data and fadeout animation on exit?

Comment: What old data specifically are you talking about? This feels like an X-Y problem, like you're using `exitProcess` as a hack to clear everything at the expense of good behavior for the end user. When they want to re-open your app, it will take longer than it would to resume the app normally.

Comment: Why not do something more gentle to "erase all data"? For example, if you are using dependency inversion frameworks, it may provide options to reset your managed singletons. Or, just reset your data through your own code.

Comment: @Tenfour04 When in use my app must stay in background and therefore data are available after normal closing the app. I also implemented a service to keep app alive. But when the activity ends I want user to be able to close the servise and reset all setting to default and close app. It think I can restore defaults with my own code, but I thought maybe closing app and free memory wold be better option. Isn't it?

Comment: Android is very good at memory management. It will close your app on its own if it's in an idle state and using memory that Android needs for some other task. If Android doesn't need the extra memory, it will leave your app loaded, and then when the user opens it again, it will be very fast. It is best not to subvert this behavior, or your app will be slow to open *every* time, because it will always be launching cold. Release specific objects when they are no longer needed, but I would not recommend fully exiting the app.

Comment: Got it. In that case it seems that finishAffinity() would be best here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case someone also wish to also remove the app from recent stack:

val activityManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager

activityManager.appTasks.forEach { task ->
task.setExcludeFromRecents(true) }

activity.finishAffinity()